# I'm trying to script changing group ID in /etc/passwd to name for every user

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to script changing group ID in /etc/passwd to name for every user but I just can't find solution. I know `cat /etc/passwd | grep GROUP_NAME | sed "s/GROUP_ID/GROUP_NAME/"`  works just fine, but I need to do it for over 80 groups in 1 script and typing every single one out is just pointless.
I tried something like

```
for i in `seq 1 87`; do
file="/home/Public/testing/groups.txt"
while read -r
do
sed  -n ${i}p | sed "s/$i/test/"
done < "$file"
done
```

where `groups.txt` file consists of GROUP_NAME:GROUP_ID which I cut out of `/etc/group` file.

The problem is that GROUP_ID isn't the same as row number as there are 87 rows and last group has ID of 1029 so it looks like this:

```
bin:test
sys:test
adm:test
tty:test
disk:test
lp:test
mail:test
news:test
uucp:test
man:12
proxy:13
kmem:15
dialout:20
```

As you can see, it stops changing after GROUP_ID = 12 because i=11 for that GROUP_ID

Other solution I tried was

```
for i in `seq 1 87`; do
file="/home/Public/testing/groups.txt"
while IFS=: read -r f1 f2
do
sed  -n ${i}p | sed "s/$f2/$f1/"
done < "$file"
done
```

and the result is:

```
daemon:1
bin:2
sys:3
adm:4
tty:5
disk:6
lp:7
mail:8
news:9
uucp:1root
```

so it only changes every `0` to `root`, because it reads only the first line which is `root:0`

Comment: Please, show a sample `/etc/passwd` and the expected output. And do not post them as images but as text for testing solutions.

Comment: `I'm trying to script changing group ID in /etc/passwd to name for every user` I do not understand. What is changing to what and how? Is GROUP_ID a number or a string literally written in `groups.txt`? You want to change users primary group or the IDs assigned to groups? Why not use standard linux utilities like `groupmod`/`usermod`/etc? `Sadly I can't post screenshots` Happily! Please do not post screenshots. As for posting scripts results _as text_ you may create a copy of /etc/passwd, randomize and remove some data and post it then (as text!) to create an [MCVE].

Comment: ok, quick example of what I'm trying to do:
/etc/passwd:
`root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync`
/etc/groups:
`root:x:0:
daemon:x:1:
bin:x:2:
sys:x:3:
adm:x:4:`
expected result:
`root:x:0:*root*:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:*daemon*:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:*bin*:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:*sys*:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:*adm*:sync:/bin:/bin/sync`
GROUP_ID replaced by GROUP_NAME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace each group ID in `/etc/passwd` with the group name, there is a way to use the `id` command.

```
while IFS=: read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7
do
  echo $f1:$f2:$f3:$(id -g -n $f1):$f5:$f6:$f7
done < /etc/passwd
```

If you want to replace using the `groups.txt` file, there is a way to use an array.
But if group ID doesn't exist in the `groups.txt` file, it becames empty.

```
declare -A groups
file="groups.txt"
while IFS=: read -r f1 f2
do
  groups[$f2]=$f1
done < "$file"
while IFS=: read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7
do
  echo $f1:$f2:$f3:${groups[$f4]}:$f5:$f6:$f7
done < /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know about the ```id``` command :D I created ```groups.txt``` to cut out only the GROUP_ID and GROUP_NAME from /etc/group file hoping it will get any easier. Anyway, thanks for the solution, I learned something new thanks to that

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
 awk -F: '{ "id -g -n "$1 | getline gnam;OFS=":";$4 ="*"gnam"*" }1' /etc/passwd
```

With the field delimiter set to : use awk getline to read the result of id -g -n $1 into a variable gnam. Use this and substitute $4 (the group id for *gnam*). Use 1 to print the resulting amended line